# How to stop an application from automatically starting

Tags: autostart, software-uninstall

How do I prevent an application from launching when I boot up my laptop (Toshiba Satellite C655)?  My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Open the launcher, launch the program "Startup Applications", untick the box of the program that should not open automatically.